# C# export to excel using string builder - positioning

Tags: c#

I'm trying to export to excel

here is my code:

```
if (dt != null)
                {
                    Response.Clear();

                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;   filename=FileBrowser_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".xls");

                    Response.Charset = "";

                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

                    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();

                    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite =
                     new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

                    grdEmpDetails.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
                    string strHead = string.Empty;
                    strHead = "File Details";
                    StringBuilder strbn = new StringBuilder();
                    strbn.Append("<table cellpadding = '0' cellspacing ='0' border = '0' width = '500px'><tr><td align='right'></td></tr></table>");
                    strbn.Append("<div style='text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background-color:White; width:100%;font-size:large'> " + strHead + "</div>");
                    strbn.Append("<div><tr><td colspan = '4'><table cellpadding = '0' cellspacing ='0' border='0' width = '100%'>");
                    strbn.Append("<tr><td colspan = '4'><table cellpadding = '0' cellspacing ='0' border='0' width = '100%' style='border:solid 1px black'>");
                    strbn.Append("<tr><td colspan = '4'><br /><br /><br /></td></tr>");
                    strbn.Append("<tr></td><td colspan = '4' >Employer ID : " + objB1.EmpId + "</td>");
                    strbn.Append("<td colspan = '4' >File Creation Date : " + objB1.FileCreatedDate + "</td></tr>");
                    strbn.Append("<tr></td><td colspan = '4'  >File Creation Time : " + objB1.FileCreatedTime + "</td>");
                    strbn.Append("<td colspan = '4'  >Employee Count : " + objB1.TotalEmployees + "</td></tr>");
                    strbn.Append("<tr></td><td colspan = '4'  >Total Salary : " + objB1.TotalSalary + "</td>");
                    strbn.Append("<td colspan = '4'  >Salary Month :  " + objB1.SalaryMonth + "</td></tr></table></td></tr></div>");

                    strbn.Append(stringWrite.ToString());

                    Response.Output.Write(strbn);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.Close();
                }
```

Export works fine. But I need to change the position of the whole table.

Now the table starts at position A1 in excel. I've to start at B2 so that there is some margin in the top and left in the excel.

Comment: do you have a sample result from excel?

Comment: Is there any way to leave some space in the left side or leave 2 columns and start from 3rd column in the excel?

Comment: Why are you string building XML when there are excellent XML libraries?

Comment: Try to add blank text from append.. there is other options but its a very long discussion.